# How to check task status in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'd like to know how can i check status of an asynchronous task in c#.
I have a save method to save users, and i'd like to run a background task to update them after the save.

I'm in framework 4.0, here is my code to begin the task

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = null;
 task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {                   
             beginTask();
       });
```

My problem is the task take some times to end (near 7 mins) so if someone do several user saves, the task is runned several times, so i'd like to check before running the task if the function beginTask() is already running to avoid to have a lot of background tasks are running.

Thanks

Comment: What happens at the end of your task? Is your task object stored somewhere to check it before running?

Comment: yes, BeginTask() saves user one by one to update a field. So it takes a long time because i need to wait 5s to update a user because i call an API i can't request more than one time every 5s. That's why i'd like to check if beginTask() is already running to avoid to execute it if two or more saves occurs while a previous call is running

Comment: what about disabling the UI button while the command is in progress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found better solution. Check if it suits you.

```
public class TaskDemo
{
    private static AutoResetEvent autoReset = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    Action beginTask = () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method start");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    };

    public void RunTask()
    {
        Task myTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                autoReset.WaitOne();
                beginTask();
            }).ContinueWith(t => autoReset.Set());
    }
}
```

And simply console app test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TaskDemo td = new TaskDemo();
        // Simulation multiple requests 
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        td.RunTask();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        td.RunTask();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        td.RunTask();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        td.RunTask();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        td.RunTask();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        td.RunTask();
    }
```

The clue is to use `AutoResetEvent` to signal task state and

```
Task myTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                autoReset.WaitOne();
                beginTask();
            }).ContinueWith(t => autoReset.Set());
```

to change its state during run and after finish (`ContinueWith(t => autoReset.Set()`).

Comment: `StartNew` should be avoided, and this should not be done with a class field, it doesn't even marked as `volatile`, which is dangerous too. You need to use auto reset event here

Comment: Why? Task.Run would be better?

Comment: @VMAtm I've change my answer according to your comment. Is it better now?

Comment: @daniell89 I hope yes :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe try do it this way-
Initialise your task object:

```
Task task = new Task(begintask);
```

And add new method to run it, for example:

```
public void StartTask(Task t)
{
    if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
        return;
    else
        t.Start();
}
```

Of course you can add more conditions depend of task's states.

Comment: nice code but the problem is everytime i'll save users, it will create a new task with status "created", so i can't test is the previous BeginTask() is still running or not

Comment: Do you really need to create new tsks? Maybe just try to add task as private field to your class, then assign to it appropriate method and start it (StartTask method in my code).

Comment: No i don't need, but how can i assign my class property without using "new Task(beginTask());" ? I have a null reference error because my property is never instanciate

Comment: I've added new answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Each [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) object has a [Task.Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.status(v=vs.110).aspx) property of type [TaskStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be queried if you already have the task object. It will tell you whether the task is running, finished, cancelled, etc.

If you want to check if ANY task is running that particular chunk of functionality that may be more difficult. One possible suggestion would be keeping a Task variable globally accessible for that reason and any time they tried to run that functionality the code did:

> Check the global to see if one is running.
>
> **If** **not** create a new Task to run it and assign it to the global variable
>
> **Else** perform whatever handling you wanted to do if it was already running (wait for it to finish perhaps?)

It sounds like you're a) misunderstanding tasks a bit and b) need to take a look at your solution design.

A task is an object representing a piece of work to be done. A task is NOT the BeginTask method itself. The BeginTask method is more or less just a set of instructions to carry out. It doesn't have any state. Individual Tasks which implement those instructions do have a state which can be queried.

If you want to make it so only one Task could be run per user you'd just have to somewhere globally store a collection of Tasks per user (such as a Dictionary with the Key being the user).

This would ideally be created and stored in either some sort of governing class that contains this section of application functionality or in the outer program if it is one.

To make reference to your comment of "i need to avoid to create a new task everytime i save my users", for this you're going to have to adapt that particular piece of code to check the stored status of any running Tasks. So in my idea above you'd alter that piece of functionality to check if a Task exists for the user you're saving in the Dictionary of already begun tasks and if it does, check the status of it.

If you're not sure though please keep asking questions in the comments. Perhaps if you gave more information on how the system this is in, is structured I'd be better able to assist.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes but i'm in a class, and i need to avoid to create a new task everytime i save my users. BeginTask() must be executed only if it isn't in "running" status. Everytime i save my users, it creates a new task with status "created" so i can't check if beginTask() is already running due to a previous users save

Comment: @VincentDucroquet I've updated my answer with a reply to your comment, it was too long to be a comment itself. If I've misunderstood something please keep questioning me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use property [Task.IsCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [Task.Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

And by the way try to investigation of this method [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx)
I think using of `Task.ContinueWith` is better way for multitask solutions.

See example below which explain my suggestion with using `Task.ContinueWith`:

```cs
System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = null;
if (task==null)
{
    task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        beginTask();
        
    });
    return;
}

if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
{
    task.ContinueWith((x) =>
    {
        beginTask();

    });
}
else
{
    task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        beginTask();

    });

}
```

This implementation can resolve scope of potential problem like:

- How to keep previous Task
- When should system launch previous Tasks

Comment: nice code too, but i'm in a class (user class) and everytime i save users it creates a new task, that's my problem. What is need is a way to check in threads if beginTask() is currently running or not. If i can check that, i can block another beginTask() execution

Comment: You mean : way to check last Task status inside beginTask method, right?